# Laravel-5.5: Why does not work my validator code?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have simple function for check sender email.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'recipient' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
        'sender' => [
            'required',
            Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('email', Auth::user()->email);
            }),
        ],
    ], $this->validator_messages());
}
```

Why not work this code? I only must check sender email with auth user email.

Comment: what does the error says ?

Comment: `Constant expression contains invalid operations`

Comment: Why are you doing this ? $query = new User

Comment: what if you delete Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query = new User) {
                $query->where('email', Auth::user()->email);
            }), line, what happens??

Comment: Have you defined `User` at the top of the file? `use \App\User;`?

Comment: `$query = new User` should be `$query = new User()`?

Comment: I have error in line with code `Rule::exists` and at the top all needed includes I wrote.

Comment: you dont need to instantiate the `($query = new User)` try `($query)` first .. i think `exists('users')` will already know where the $query should execute ..

Comment: Did you change `$query = new User` to only $query? You don't need to initialise the $query variable again, the exists method should construct a query based on the table `users` that you passed into the method

Comment: what is sender mean?? id or email??

Comment: I am sorry, but I think you don't need to send the `sender` value in your form. If you require `sender` value be exactly same with `Auth::user()->email`, just assign it directly. No need to validate. Because `Auth::user()->email` will return valid current logged in user email address.

Comment: `sender` field email must be equivalent with current user email. How do make it?

Comment: Now taken error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sender' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `sender` = google@gmail.com and (`email` = google@gmail.com))`

Comment: Yes @Dharma Saputra you say right but I want only test my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make a query in DB, because `auth()->user()` object is already loaded. So, you could use the `In` rule:

```
'sender' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in([auth()->user()->email]),
    ],
],
```

Comment: `sender` filed email must be equivalent with Auth user email. How I can do so?

Comment: @MaxNet if you want to check if email from the form equals authenticated user email, you can use the `In` rule as I've shown.

Comment: If this code right then what I must write in validator messages if email not  equivalent with auth email. For example so `sender.exists` or another?

Comment: @MaxNet `sender.in` I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey Mezenin

Answer (score 0):

I think you must create a rule class for validation for example:

```
php artisan make:rule TestUserRule
```

And in this class implement 2 method : passes($attribute, $value) and message methods.

For example:

```
public function passes($attribute,$value){

      //write your conditions here you must return boolean value here
      return User::where('email',Auth::user()->email)->count();
}
```

Or you can use laravel default exists validation rule